# update multiple columns with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 4 columns. I am trying to update only that values of the columns which is like(equal) to the value come in loop.

```
for ($a=0; $a<$i ; $a++) {  
            $sql= "update table1 set 
            col1= CASE when col1 like '$distval[$a]' then col1='$arr[$a]' else col1 end,
            col2=CASE when col2 like '$distval[$a]' then col2='$arr[$a]' else col2 end,
            col3=CASE when col3 like '$distval[$a]' then col3='$arr[$a]' else col3 end, 
            col4=CASE when col4 like '$distval[$a]' then col4='$arr[$a]' else col4 end";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
```

Let me explain the code:

> $distval: is the array which contains the distinct values of all the four columns which i want to update with values entered by the users.
>
> $arr: is another array of the text fields of same number as '$distval'. Now the value enter in the first text field should update all the values in table like(equals to) first value of '$distvalue'.

The code doesn't update anything without any error.

Comment: `case` statements aren't programming code. you can't "execute" an assignment inside them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the colX='$arr[$a]'  inside the then you need only '$arr[$a]'

```
$sql= "update table1 set 
          col1= CASE when col1 like '%". $distval[$a]. "%' then '$arr[$a]' else col1 end,
          col2= CASE when col2 like '%". $distval[$a]. "%' then '$arr[$a]' else col2 end,
          col3= CASE when col3 like '%". $distval[$a]. "%' then '$arr[$a]' else col3 end, 
          col4= CASE when col4 like '%". $distval[$a]. "%' then '$arr[$a]' else col4 end";
```

Comment: still not working. I think there should be 'where' somewhere in the query, not sure.

Comment: In your  query there is not a where so i think you  want update all the rows in table  ... what do you mean with  still not working. .. you have an error  .. .. you have an unexpected result?

Comment: Could be you have some problem accessing $distval[$a] and using like so i have used string concatenation for the query  .. i have update the answer

Comment: no error. no unexpected result. it run without any action. No i want to update only those values which are same to '$distval'... not whole row.

Comment: one .. four .. five  .. what are  these terms?

Comment: If you don't see any action this mean that your like  '$distval[$a]' don't match  (and so colN = colN   alias nothings change)  could be that you problem is in the like condition  .. update your question and show me a brief sample

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. The main problem was assignment inside case.

Answer (score 0):

The `=` does not make sense for the `then`.  The correct `case` would look like:

```
update table1
   set col1 = (CASE when col1 like '$distval[$a]' then '$arr[$a]' else col1 end),
       col2 = (CASE when col2 like '$distval[$a]' then '$arr[$a]' else col2 end),
       col3 = (CASE when col3 like '$distval[$a]' then '$arr[$a]' else col3 end), 
       col4 = (CASE when col4 like '$distval[$a]' then '$arr[$a]' else col4 end);
```

I would strongly encourage you to use parameterized queries, rather than dumping the values directly in the query string.

Comment: still not working. I think there should be 'where' somewhere in the query, not sure.